# Check if the superclass is java.lang.Object

Tags: java, reflection

I use

```
if (clazz.getSuperclass().getName() == "java.lang.Object")
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`if ( clazz.getSuperclass( ) == Object.class )`

There are 2 problems with your original implementation:

1. `getSuperclass` may return `null` and you get NPE when you call getName
2. You use identity equality with a String ( `==` instead of `equals` ).  Strangely enough it may work in this case as `"java.lang.Object"` string is probably internalized.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
if (clazz.getSuperclass().equals(java.lang.Object.class))
```

Comment: This may throw NPE if clazz is primitive or `java.lang.Object`. Probably `Object.class.equals( clazz.getSuperclass( ) )` is more robust.  Also `java.lang.Class` is one of the classes where it's OK to use identity compare.

Comment: @Alexander, good point, thanks. I was not _quite_ sure about the identity compare, so I used `equals` - thus getting myself bitten in the other leg :-)